# Votes display under Linked Questions is broken

Tags: bug, related-questions, linked-questions, sidebar

I've noticed this only on MSE; the number of votes under the linked or related sections gets displayed in more than one rows if the number of votes exceeds 99 votes (two digits):

[image: MSE-1]

and

[image: MSE-2]

Using Google Chrome Version 34.0.1847.132 on Debian